# Does making a IIFE make sense in a Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Working in JavaScript in a browser I always use a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to save global name space pollution.

```
(function() {})();
```

but as Node.js uses common.js and almost every file is a module in itself, does it make sense to make IIFEs (if using ES5) when starting new code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

Internally, Node already wraps the contents of the module with a function to create a new scope.

You can find the specifics [in this file](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f385f77f1d011786cb1c5e80f257fa043f4c608b/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js); the function by which the module contents are wrapped is defined [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f385f77f1d011786cb1c5e80f257fa043f4c608b/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js#L511-L514), and [in this method](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f385f77f1d011786cb1c5e80f257fa043f4c608b/lib/internal/bootstrap_node.js#L516-L534) you see that after wrapping the module code, it's executed almost immediately (similar to what an IIFE does).